# Is there a way to get an image into Core Data for use in the iPad Simulator?

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage, ios-simulator

I have a bug in my iPad app where it's not either saving or retrieving the correct image from a Core Data store.  So, when using the Simulator I need to have several distinct small images in each entity so I can see what's going wrong.

Is there a way to get an image into the Core Data store on the Mac? (I don't care what they look like, as long as they are different from any of the others). I did a search in Google and SO and found nothing appropriate.

Comment: Not without putting them in there with code. And that seems to be exactly your problem... Maybe post the code instead?

Comment: I found this: (http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/04/using-the-camer-of-ios-simulators/), which just might do the trick...  Please write your comment as an answer so I can give you the points.

Comment: My comment wasn't really an answer. If the link you provided helped you out, post it as an answer yourself (not just the link, but an explanation of what you did with a reference) and mark that as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the way those images are parsed into Core Data in your app? That will give you a persistent store containing those images from which you can then retrieve them later.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The Simulator does not have the capability to simulate the camera on a device; that said, how am I supposed to "parse" the image into Core Data from my app, which would be running on the XCode Simulator?

Comment: Ok I didn't understand that you were talking about photo's from the devices library. However, you can place some debugging code that delivers the images, instead of the camera. Then at least you are able to debug the storage and retrieval of images, regardless of where they came from.